# WinRT ObservableCollection delete operation with ListView

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime

I'm developing a WinRT 8.1 application in which I'm binding my `ListView` control to the `ObservableCollection` as this

```
            <ListView x:Name="DetailsViews" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" Width="395">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" Holding="grid_Holding" Height="60" Width="395">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeleteButton" Text="delete" Click="DeleteSelectedItem"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DetailTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="32" Height="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=Height}" Text="{Binding DetailValue}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Width="320"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is my code behind file.

```
myList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

myList.Add(new Person() { DetailTitle = "Key", DetailValue = "Value"  });

DetailsViews.ItemsSource = myList;
```

I need to know, that how to delete items from the `ObservableCollection` so that on each deletion, it updates the UI. Here is my delete code but it is not working because `SelectedIndex` is returning -1 each time if I put a breakpoint there.

```
private void DeleteSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.myList.RemoveAt(this.DetailsViews.SelectedIndex);
}
```

How do I update the UI and what problem it could be?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Where are you calling `DeleteSelectedItem`? Could you show us the full XAML code of your ListView?

Comment: Sorry I can't post my whole XAML code right there, can you please tell me, that where DeleteSelectedItem should define? It is not a property of the ListView in the intellisense? I'm using ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's the most basic example that I can think of with the basic empty template, and it works, that's why @KooKiz said that your code looks OK.

So you'll need to post at least the part that you are declaring the ListView in order to get help with your issue.

Xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView Name="ItemsView" ItemsSource="{Binding items}"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Test Remove"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<String> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            items.Add("First Item");
            items.Add("Second Item");
            items.Add("Third Item");
            items.Add("Fourth Item");

            ItemsView.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            items.RemoveAt(ItemsView.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

**OK thanks to the update of your code, I was able to find out what's wrong** with it and I have a quick solution for you, and some advice if it's not exactly what you want from it :)

**Explanation**

I imagine you have a method handling the holding event like this:

```
private void grid_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

so what happens is **you fire the holding event while holding with your finger but this event does not select any item, because items are selected on touches/clicks**, and that's why when you click delete it's without selected element.

I've tested to select an item with single touch and then do the holding part and it's working correctly.

**The solution**

So now that we know what is happening there are different solutions depending on what you want to achieve at the end, for simplicity I'll assume the easiest to implement :) .

Lets assume you don't use selected items in any other way than to delete them or to navigate (no selection of list view items needed)

So first we edit the ListView in XAML to be **SelectionMode="None"**
(note that the given fix works without it but it might confuse the user)

```
<ListView x:Name="DetailsViews" 
          SelectionMode="None"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Grid.Row="3" 
          Width="395">
```

then you need to add a property in your code behind to hold the value of the selected item because you're not going to use the selection (index or item) of the ListView.

```
public Person SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

and then we need to slightly modify the deletion and the holding handlers to use the new property

```
private void DeleteSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //items.RemoveAt(DetailsViews.SelectedIndex);
    items.Remove(SelectedItem);
}

private void grid_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Person;
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

So what these do now is: Delete item now remove by the object not by index

And the object is coming from the holding handler where you set the selected item to be the DataContext of the current pressed element (which is the DataContext of the ListView element, which is Person)

I would advice you to add some defensive programming and do some checks to guard your program from crashes/exceptions. Also I'd advice you to go over some courses on how to use MVVM if you are doing anything other than a test project.

Cheers and happy coding ;)

Comment: Actually I'm doing the same thing, but my ListView SelectedIndex is -1 which results an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Is there any way to make SelectedIndex as the same as ObservableCollection?

Comment: Are you selecting an element from the list, maybe the selection mode is set to none or something like this. Or if you're binding the selected index to some variable it's conflicting... will be easier if you paste some of the code.

You could try having a property (in your ViewModel or Code Behind if that's what you're going to use) for the Selected Index, or to the Selected Item, and then use the other remove method (by Item)

Comment: Here is the code that I'm using

In the constructor it is

myList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

            myList.Add(new Person() { DetailTitle = "Key", DetailValue = "Value" });

            DetailsViews.ItemsSource = myList;


private void DeleteSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.myList.RemoveAt(this.DetailsViews.SelectedIndex);
        }

Sorry for not showing the code with indents.

Comment: @JanshairKhan This part of the code is not the problematic one, if you receive -1 for selected index every time then the problem lies in the way you bind your data or in the way you're using the app (eg if you doesn't select any item before you press delete). However you have to remove the +1 part of your code because it will cause out of range exception if you select the last item

Comment: @JanshairKhan please post your xaml or at least the part with the ListView declaration, better do an edit to your original answer to be able to format it better than in comment

Comment: thanks for commenting, I've update the XAML code and notify me the issue. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @JanshairKhan I've edited my answer an hour or two ago but forgot to notify you.

Comment: Thank you @kirotab, you're genius. Hope you will help me again. :)